# How to display the results of reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am learning react js. I found an example of how to create a button using react. I downloaded Atom, and then copied the code to Atom, but all the code is
underscored with red. how can i see the result of the below posted code please.

**code**:

```
var React = require('react');

var buttonStyle = {
margin: '10px 10px 10px 0'
};

var Button = React.createClass({
render: function () {
return (
  <button
    className="btn btn-default"
    style={buttonStyle}
    onClick={this.props.handleClick}>{this.props.label}</button>
);
}
});

module.exports = Button;
```

Comment: You need to install all the corresponding packages to be able to render react. You can start with this tutorial https://scotch.io/courses/getting-started-with-react/creating-your-first-component. But to fix those red lined in Atom you should install this plugin https://atom.io/packages/react

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please make sure that the file is with the extension of jsx. For example: index.jsx . It is because .js extension cannot read through react file.

Instead of copy and paste example code, I recommend for beginner to use this create-react-app boilerplate as the starting point. Please see this github link https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app to get started and just follow the step by step and you should be good to go.